# Homotopic from $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ and the identity map

Tags: manifolds, homotopy-theory

Let $X^n$ be a connected, orientable and compact manifold. Let $F: X \times X \rightarrow X \times X$, given by $f(x,y)=(y,x)$.

My goal is to show that $f$ can not  be homotopic to the identity of $X \times X$. It is clear, to, me, that $\deg(f)=(-1)^{n^2}$, and, so, if $n$ is odd, then, $f$ can't be homotopic to the identity, but I do not know how to proceed if $n$ is even, since it would give $\deg(f)=1$, and, so, it could be homotopic to the identity.

Comment: Do you know the Kunneth formula?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I am not there yet :(

Comment: Do you know that the top homology group $H_n(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito yeah!

Comment: Great.  I'll write up an answer now.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks, man, and sorry for bothering :(

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it seems that you are in the wrong question, dude :~

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez you actually meant about a question that I've posted (which was quite dumb, my the way) and deleted it 5 min later? The one you've sent ONE comment? Don't mind, man. Question undeleted. Hopes it makes you feel happier, LOL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a point $x_0\in X$ and consider the inclusion $i:X\rightarrow X\times X$ given by $i(x) = (x,x_0)$.

Let $p_1:X\times X\rightarrow X$ and $p_2:X\times X\rightarrow X$ be the two projections:  $p_1(x,y) = x$ and $p_2(x,y) = y$.

The composition $p_1\circ i:X\rightarrow X$ is the identity map, so it induces the identity function on $H_n(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  The composition $p_2\circ i$ is the constant $x_0$-map, so it induces the $0$ function on $H_n(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Thus, we see that $p_1\circ i$ is not homotopic to $p_2\circ i$.

Now assume for a contradiction that the identity map $id_{X\times X}$ is homotopic to the switching map $f$.  Then $p_2 = p_1\circ f$ must be homotopic to $p_1\circ Id_{X\times X}$.  This implies $p_2\circ i$ is homotopic to $p_1\circ Id_{X\times X}\circ i = p_1 \circ i$, a contradiction.

Comment: I was wrapping my head around (Maybe it's not the right use of this idiomatic expression?) trying to think how to use your hint in the comment section. +1 for this beautiful answer

Comment: @Didier:  Glad you like it.  By the way, the proof extends to non-orientable closed manifolds almost verbatim.  Just use the fact that $H_{n-1}$ contains a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  It also works on non-contractible (possibly non-compact) things, with small modification.  By Whitehead, there must be a non-trivial homotopy group, then use that instead of $H_n$.  So, I guess a way of phrasing this is that for $X$ a CW-complex, the switching map $f:X\times X\rightarrow X\times X$ is homotopic to the identity iff $X$ is contractible.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, I'd like to give +1 more than one time, rs. Quite a beautiful way of looking at the problem. Congrats, man!

Comment: Oh, @JasonDeVito, in a few days I'll probably try to solve it using the Kunneth Formula you said :)

Comment: @Didier:  (While American English is my native language, I don't really consider myself an expert in it!)  When I think "Wrapping my head around" something, I imagine a situation where all the relevant information has been given, and I'm just having trouble understanding it.  So, I, personally, wouldn't use "Wrapping my head around" to describe this situation, since "hints" are, by definition, lacking full information.

Comment: @Didier Thank you for both the Differential Topology and (American) English courses then!

Comment: @Didier:  You're very welcome!  I'm actually curious if other native AmE speakers attach the same nuance to the phrase that I did.  I certainly wasn't aware of the nuance until I tried to type my prior comment.  I'm also curious how it varies across the pond.....